# How to conditionally render a DIV and REACT component for OPENING and CLOSING tags?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a piece of code that should be rendered based on the condition applied. For example:

```
isMobile ? <MyComponent> : <div className={styles.myclassStyle}>

....other code goes here....

isMobile ? </MyComponent> : </div>
```

if **isMobile** is true, then **MyComponent** should be selected otherwise the html element
 **div** . Is it possible to do so? Any alternate solution?

Answer (score 7):

you would conditionally render the entire bit of code and you would would have to return it in parenthesis with a single root element. so for instance

```
{
  isMobile ? (
    <MyComponent>
      // this code runs if isMobile === true
      // ... code for MyComponent
    </MyComponent>
  ) : (
    <div className={styles.myclassStyle}>
      // this code runs of isMobile === false
      // ... code for the div goes here
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This creates redundancy in the code. The point is to use different components using conditional statement.

Comment: what you're trying to do in your original code isn't how conditional rendering works. you should look into composition of components, or abstracting all the markup in that code to other components so you could reduce it to `isMobile ? <MyComponent /> : <AnActualComponentNotADiv />` and reduce the amount of code you write. react is about creating reusable components and composing them elegantly

Comment: @Eid Believe it or not, it is actually less redundant that what you were trying; 1 ternary condition versus 2. This is (one of) react's idiomatic ways to conditionally render one "thing" or the "other". https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @Michael, yes I believe React does not support such condition.